# when testing a directive, I get typeerror compile is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, directive

When I try to test my directive I get the TypeError: compile is not a function.
Here is my test case:

```
describe('directive tests', function () {
var element, $compile, scope;

beforeEach(module('App'));

beforeEach(inject(function (_$compile_, $rootScope) {
    $compile = _$compile_;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
}));

it('should be Hello', function () {
    element = $compile('<div Hello></div>')(scope);
    ...
});
```

});

If I comment the line that define the module, (beforeEach(modue('App')),  the compile works, but I can't get reference to my directive.

Comment: have you reference all the component file, which has `App` module with components on your `SpecRunner.html`?

Comment: I'm using Karma, and it is well configured, all dependencies are there.

Comment: My old directive tests have this beforeEach(module('app', templateURL));. I think that called the angular html2js preprocessor, but hontestly I've forgotten. The way I write directives now is I test the controller and the main thing the directive does is just marry the controller and the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In karma.conf.js, add file containing reference to app module

```
  files : [
  'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'app/js/**/*.js',
  'test/unit/**/*.js'
],
```

Comment: my karma file: files: [
          'wwwroot/lib/angular/angular.js',
          'wwwroot/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',

          'Scripts/**/*.js',
          'Tests/**/*.js'
        ],

Comment: Try this please, change your directive's name to lowercase and run it again. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25364260/angularjs-directive-is-breaking-based-on-first-character-of-directive-name

Comment: I found the problem, my app references a module that it's not inculed in the karma.conf file.